# Python to exe for windows

Tags: python, exe

I currently use python 3. I also want a single exe file  as the end product. What application would I use to combine all my libraries with my exe?
I tried cx_freeze but it gives me library, dll files.

Comment: cx_freeze should work, but there's also py2exe, and maybe more... You should give more information about your problem (ie. your `setup.py` file, better description of the results you get, etc.) so people can actually help you with your problem.

Comment: My guess is it would work fine and your `setup.py` is the problem.  Unless you post it and give more info, there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: Use pyinstaller it will work

Comment: I find py2exe does the job sufficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post on StackOverflow suggests the use of py2exe and cython to compile your python files into a .dll executable.

[How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Realizing that ^^ is not actually an answer...

e.g.

You have a scipt named script.py

create a setup.py file that will tell py2exe what to do.

setup.py example:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['script.py']
```

run from console "python setup.py py2exe"

you should now have an executable named script.py

reference: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial for this most simple example...

Comment: Py2exe is not python 3 ready though